# Load External Cross Domain HTML Content in iFrame vs. from Asynchronously JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an HTML widget, i.e., HTML Content that can be included in other pages. So lets say my content is from domain A and a page in domain B includes the widget from domain A. I see two ways to include the cross domain content in a page of domain B.

Note: The widget will show some diagrams, i.e., data visualisation.

**Variante 1:**

Using an iFrame.

```
<iframe src="domain_A_url_to_widget" width="200" height="400" name="foreignWidget">
  <p>no Browser support</p>
</iframe>
```

**Variante 2:**

Using asynchronously JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(d){
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0],
        p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
    p.type = 'text/javascript';
    p.async = true;
    p.src = '//domainA.com/js/widget.js';
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
  })(document);
</script>
```

**1. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both variants?**

**2. Is there any possibility to use JQuery and CSS in variant 2?**

**3. Can the user interact with my widget in both variants event if the widget loads content with ajax?**

Comment: 1 is well covered, 2 is yes.

Comment: FYI Option 2 is not asynchronous.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why is it not asynchronous?

Comment: @dandavis where is 1 well covered?

Comment: @confile because you're just loading a script from an external resource. There is nothing asynchronous about it, aside from the browsers usual method of handling multiple content requests.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please post an answer how I make it asynchronously?

Comment: @confile it's not an issue that it isn't, I was just correcting what you had stated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so how can I make it async?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in option 2 the inline script itself is not asynchronous, but the script load will be asynchronous (which I think is the point of the question).

Comment: @Christophe it will load the content asynchronously with other requests for images etc. however DOMReady won't fire until all scripts on the page have been loaded, so in that sense it is not async.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What do you suggest to solve this async problem?

Comment: @confile why do you see that as a problem? It's actually a good thing to be able to know when the script has been loaded if you plan to use it on the page.

Comment: How can I load JQuer before my custom script is loaded? How can I ensure that my script is only executed after JQuery was executed?

Comment: @confile these questions are too broad for a forum. You'll need to open a thread with a more specific example.

Comment: @Christophe so I should make a new question on the JQuery part?

Comment: Definitely, and show what you've tried (just like you did in this question). The assumption is that you've done some research before posting.

Comment: option 2 IS a-synchronous, as are all dom-added script tags; it's hard-coded script tags that are sync.

Comment: @Christophe why not using iFrame it is much simpler to implement and when you do not want to modify something on the hosted site it will be enough?

Comment: @confile that's what I said in my answer, see below.

Comment: @Christophe do I get problems with page tracking when using the iFrame?

Comment: your iframe is its own page, separate from the host page.

Comment: @Christophe why do facebook, google plus, twitter use version 2 when they do not change content on the page?

Comment: @confile again, these are broad questions, not suitable for this comment format: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe creates a sandboxed environment.

Benefit: no risk of conflict with the main page (for example styles).

Downside: because of cross-domain limitations, it is very difficult for the content of the iframe to interact with the main page.

Examples:

- option 1 is fine for ads, or for a weather widget
- option 2 will be easier for a widget that highlights keywords on the main page.

You can of course use jQuery in variant 2 (remember: jQuery is just a bunch of JavaScript code). You can use css too, you'll load it via a link or style tag (the same way you loaded your script via a script tag).

Comment: How will I load and activate JQuery in variante to such that I can use it in my custom widget.js script? Can the user interact with my widget in both variants?

Comment: You can include the jQuery code in your widget.js file (that's the easiest way), or load it via a script tag inside widget.js, or load it before widget.js.

Comment: The user can interact with the widget in both variants. It's hard to be more specific as it will really depend on the widget itself.

Comment: Can you post some sample code how I can load JQuery and how my script uses it on, i.e., after JQuery is ready?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the contents of an `iframe` are effectively their own page, whereas if you pull in some HTML via JavaScript it will become part of the DOM of the original page. As you're calling it a "widget", I'd guess that this is sort of a component of the original page you want to add in, so option 2 is the better one in my opinion - this isn't really what `iframe` is meant for.

Comment: Why do you think variant 2 is better?

Comment: I'm assuming you want this widget to have some interaction with other parts of the page, and/or vice/versa? As another poster said, `iframe`s are sandboxed which makes that extremely difficult.

Also, from a performance perspective, because an `iframe` is essentially an entire new page so an entire new DOM and rendering tree is constructed, this is all computationally expensive compared to adding another chunk of HTML to an existing page.